# CPLEX opl soft objective of grouping high priority stock

Tags: cplex, opl

The goal of the opl model below is to choose the freights with total minimum cost to fulfill all orders, I have a soft optimization objective `objective1` where it's to try to put all orders with `CategoryPriority` on one freight or as small number of freight as possible. But how to encode that objective? (in the example below, order 2 and 3 is optimal to be on the same truck)

current .mod file (model file)

```
tuple TFreightTypes {
  key string Destination;
  key string VehicleType;
  int TotalWeight;
  key string Company;
  int Cost;
};

tuple TOrders {
  key int OrderNumber;
  float Weight;
  string ClientId;
  string Destination;
  string MaterialCategory;
  int CategoryPriority;
};

{TFreightTypes}    FreightTypes = ...;
{TOrders}    Orders = ...;


dvar boolean Assignment[Orders][FreightTypes];

//choose freight with total minimum cost
dexpr float objective = 
  sum(o in Orders, f in FreightTypes)
     Assignment[o][f] * f.Cost;

//try to put all orders with CategoryPriority=1 on one truck 
//dexpr float objective1 = 
  //how to do that?

minimize 0.95*objective+0.05*objective1;


subject to{

  //c1: all order must be fulfilled
  forall(o in Orders)
    sum(f in FreightTypes) Assignment[o][f]==1;       
   
}
```

.dat file (data file)

```
FreightTypes = {
    <"LONDON","Type1",20000,"SP TRANSPORTS",40000>,
    <"LONDON","Type2",20000,"SP TRANSPORTS",40000>,
    <"DURHAM","Type3",10000,"SP TRANSPORTS",30000>,

};
Orders = {
    <1,5000,"Client1","LONDON","A",0>,
    <2,1000,"Client2","DURHAM","B",1>,
    <3,2000,"Client3","LONDON","C",1>,      

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of weighted sum

minimize 0.95*objective+0.05*objective1;

you can use lexicographic :

minimize staticLex(objective,objective1);

Full example https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoomultiobjective.mod

```
int nbKids=200;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
float costBus50=625;
     
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
dvar int+ nbBus50;

dvar float cost;
dvar float co2emission;
     
minimize
  staticLex(cost,co2emission);
     
subject to
{
 cost==costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+nbBus50*costBus50;
 co2emission==nbBus50+nbBus40*1.1+nbBus30*1.2;

  40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30+nbBus50*50>=nbKids;
}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
  writeln("The minimum cost is ",cost);
  writeln("CO2 emission is ",co2emission);
  writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses ",nbBus30,
  " 30 seats buses and ", nbBus50," buses 50 seats");
}
```

which could look like the following with your model

```
tuple TFreightTypes {
  key string Destination;
  key string VehicleType;
  int TotalWeight;
  key string Company;
  int Cost;
};

tuple TOrders {
  key int OrderNumber;
  float Weight;
  string ClientId;
  string Destination;
  string MaterialCategory;
  int CategoryPriority;
};

{TFreightTypes}    FreightTypes = ...;
{TOrders}    Orders = ...;


dvar boolean Assignment[Orders][FreightTypes];

//choose freight with total minimum cost
dexpr float objective = 
  sum(o in Orders, f in FreightTypes)
     Assignment[o][f] * f.Cost;

//try to put all orders with CategoryPriority=1 on one truck 
//dexpr float objective1 = 
  //how to do that?
  
{int} priorities={o.CategoryPriority | o in Orders};
  
dvar int nbFreightPerPriority[priorities]; 
dvar float+ objective1;

minimize staticLex(objective,objective1);


subject to{
  
  forall(p in priorities) 
  nbFreightPerPriority[p]==
  sum(f in FreightTypes) (1<=sum (o in Orders:o.CategoryPriority==p) Assignment[o][f]);
  
  objective1==sum(p in priorities) nbFreightPerPriority[p];

  //c1: all order must be fulfilled
  forall(o in Orders)
    sum(f in FreightTypes) Assignment[o][f]==1;       
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, What about the part of grouping high priority stock, actually that’s the key part of the question where I did not know how to achieve